# CiviCRM API explorer menu is not visibile on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api

I installed CiviCRM  5.23.4 on Wordpress 5.4 and the `Support` menu is not visible. How do I enable and use the API explorer?
If I go to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/doc/api#explorer` I have an empty page (only the title is visible).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your CiviCRM cache CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths.

Check if the Support menu is enabled in CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Navigation Menu

The api3 explorer link is

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fapi3#explorer

Comment: Thanks @pradeep-nayak, it simply wasn't enabled, I'm stupid.

Comment: so can you mark this as answered if this post helped you to fix your problem?